# What do goblins attack when all resources are down?

Tags: clash-of-clans

The tooltip about Goblin's says

> These pesky little creaturews only have eyes for one thing: LOOT! They
>   are faster than a Spring Trap, and their hunger for resouces is
>   limitless.

Whenever I use Goblin's to attack they only attack resources and before they even get the chance to attack something else they are dead.

So what do Goblins attack something when all resources are down?

And if all resources are surrounded by walls do the goblin's attack the walls to get to the resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goblins (and all units in Clash) attack the building with their own highest priority rating. For goblins Loot has the highest priority. After that ALL other buildings get the same priority (so they attack the building the closest to them), the only exeption being walls.

If the resources are surrounded by walls the goblins will attack the walls to get to it although they will attack in the shortest distance possible rather then the most valuable spot (usually the corners).

Comment: mention also that after all recorces are destroyed they will go after the closesed building then after the closesed building after thad. this is also the case with any other troops with preference like gigants.

Comment: @codermaster Thanks for your addition. Figured that made sence but added it anyway.